# Cycles in 3D View unusably slow in scene with only 3 spheres with 6GB VRAM

Tags: cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'm new to Blender (v2.78) on a new Windows laptop (MSI GS73VR 6RF Stealth Pro).

Hardware: 16GB RAM, GeForce GTX 1060 6GB, Intel Core i7-6700HQ (~3GHz), 1920x1080 17" display

Blender: v2.78, samples set to 10; below-mentioned spheres have subsurface set to 2; rendering samples are set pretty low (around 6 to 8 for things like bounces, diffuse, glossy), CUDA is on and the graphics card appears to be recognized. Switching rendering between CPU and GPU reflects a clear difference in speed.

Last night I was doing this Blender Guru tutorial
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/earth-cycles/

With samples set to 10, as I see the host has set as well, I found Cycles rendering in the preview to be relatively snappy until I hit "adding the atmosphere" at about 19:46 in the video.

After adding that, turning on the hot pink visualization, Cycles preview rendering in the viewport slowed to a crawl. Like, unusably (the application is rendered unusable) slow. Try to rotate the view, and there is no update in the viewport at all. Then after a long (5 sec?) pause, the view jumps to the new view angle.

The fans kick in, and memory usage hits about 450MB; not enough to stress a 6GB video card I think? Many times during this part of the tutorial, Blender crashes.

If I turn off the atmosphere object from being viewed, performance returns.
The host of the video doesn't seem to be having this slowdown (granted, he's likely using a far more powerful system than me, but this tutorial isn't very heavy, I think)

This seems unusual to me for a scene which contains only 3 spheres, on a 6GB VRAM graphics card. I've found the system to be a powerhouse in gaming, including Unreal Engine 4 based games, and I think rendering (F12, 1920x1080@50%) is relatively speedy in Blender (BMW test @ 1:45, though I see lower-spec'ed machines besting me?)

One thing to note, and perhaps I don't understand how Blender manages its memory usage, I do have some relatively complex PBR node setups in the project, but those are not being used on any object in the scene. I don't think the mere existence of those in the project would have such a specific effect on Cycles in the viewport, right?

Comment: gpu rendering is known to slow down viewport display. Basically the rendering tries to consume 100% gpu time and doesn't share processor time with other apps well, it's like an extreme case of one program consuming 100% cpu on a single cpu machine.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, and will keep it mind going forward.

As for the crashing, I *may* have that solved by inspecting the texture files that came with the tutorial. They are HUGE. 20000 x 12000 sometimes. I normalized everything to 4096x2048

In deconstructing the scene, object by object, I see now that the earth object (the innermost sphere) renders quickly in the 3D viewport using Cycles, though it contains the 3 heaviest texture maps. When I add a second plain sphere around the earth with a Mix Shader (default Diffuse + default Transparent), in-view rendering slows down again.

Comment: That is a huge texture load, theres a scene worth of textures (1 texture 20k x 12k equals to 60 x 2k). If your scene renders quickly without textures, its the textures. But otherwise its the samples or lighting setup.

Comment: Well, as I said in my follow up, the object with the textures is not causing an issue, the object with transparency is. I also minimized the textures to be uniformly 2048x1024 per. There are 6 textures total. Navigating 3D viewport with a single simple transparent sphere laying in front of a diffuse sphere can be super slow with transparent texture applied, but is definitely crashing with or without textures. Installation was via Steam. I'm going to do a fresh install from Blender Foundation directly.